# stroke-dashoffset doesnt work for me

Tags: css, svg, stroke

While working with animating svg i discovered strange issue that stroke-dashoffset doesnt work for me. I want to make acheckmark to draw itself.

I created a pen so you can watch it here:
https://codepen.io/kalreg/pen/yorQaV

```
<svg>
  <path stroke="red" fill="none" stroke-width=10 stroke-dashoffset=6530  d="M5,50 L60,105 L150,5"></path>
</svg>
```

Both changing css or attribute of path from negative, through 0 to positive values doesnt change appearance of checkmark

I am not sure what am i doing wrong, so any advice would be more than appreciated.
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The animation of `stroke-dashoffset` works together with `stroke-dasharray` and you are also missing the `@keyframes` to actual have the animation:

```
path {
  stroke-dasharray: 6630;
  stroke-dashoffset: 6630;
  animation: dash 5s linear forwards;
}

@keyframes dash {
  to {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
}
```

Here is the update to your codepen:
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/mMgQMY

Comment: The length of that path is only 212.3. So a dasharray of 6630 is unnecessarily large.  Use something like 213 instead. https://codepen.io/anon/pen/qXGaOv